# Show custom dataclass-like constraint violations in VSCode editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

looking at this example

```
@dataclass
class Something:
    val1: int = 1
    val2: int
```

VSCode with Pylance shows the error "Attributes without a default cannot follow attributes with one" in the editor. This is all good.

I have my own decorator that should enforce different constraints.

```
@model
class Something:
   key1: Key[int]
   # this violates a custom constraint on having exactly one attribute of type `Key`
   key2: Key[int]
```

I have implemented `model` such that it throws an exception since there are two keys. This works too.

Now, the problem is, that the user doesn't see this error in the editor. Instead, the testing widget with pytest encounters discovery errors and the user needs to check the Python Output console to see what is going on.

How can I make violations to my custom constraints visible in the editor?

Comment: have you implemented the constraints the same as done in `dataclass`, PyLance is a static analyzer, it does not execute Python code, maybe they have duplicated the behavior of `dataclass` in there analysis rules

Comment: why do the PyLance developers say if you create an issue at the repo